# Multiple Developers working on SSRS Report

Tags: ssrs-2008, reporting-services

I've searched both SO and Google with no answers.

We have a bit of a different environment, Visual Studio 2005, TFS 2005, ASP.Net 2.0, SQLServer 2008r2.

We're using the report writer built into the SSRS report website to edit reports. For other organizations using this editing interface, what kind of procedures have you put in place to prevent multiple developers working on the same report from over writting each others work?

I'm thinking about everyone exporting the RDLs for the report they are working on and adding it to TFS, then when they want to edit a report, lock it in TFS and check in teh RDL when they are done.

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We actually use visual studio business intelligence projects to edit the reports.
They are sitting all in source safe control (tortise svn), so we know when a report is checked out or not.  We generally do not use / recommend using the report writer thats built directly into the report website, only because we are familiar with visual studio.

I think what you mentioned would work have everyone export the rdl file, but why not just put all the .rdl files into something like tortise and allow members of the team to check out a report - make modifications to the report - and then check it back in ?